# Navigating Back to a Reusable Activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

How do I navigate to a reusable activity and then navigate "UP" to the calling activity?

[image]

I have a **MainActivity** that I call:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ReusableActivity.class);
intent.put("SomeName", SomeData);
startActivity(intent);
```

And I have an **OtherActivity** that calls that **ReusableActivity** also.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(OtherActivity.this, ReusableActivity.class);
intent.put("SomeName", SomeData);
startActivity(intent);
```

In my **ReusableActivity** I have a toolbar that will display the "UP" arrow so the user can navigate back.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ReusableActivity);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    }
```

How do I get ReusableActivity to send the user back up to the Correct calling activity?

So if I am on the OtherActivity and go to ReusableActivity, when the user presses the up button, they go back to OtherActivity

Manifest File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myCompany.myApp">


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SearchView"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_search_view"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.myCompany.myApp.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SearchResultsList"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_search_results_list"
            android:parentActivityName=".SearchView"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.myCompany.myApp.SearchView" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ReusableActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_details"
            android:parentActivityName=".SearchResultsList"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.myCompany.myApp.SearchResultsList" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".OtherActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_other"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.myCompany.myApp.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: So you want the "home" button to be a "back" instead of an "up"?  Don't set `DisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)` if you don't want it to actually be an Up.  See [Navitation with Back and Up](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html)

Comment: For some reason if I am on Other and go to Reusealbe, when the user press the back button they are taken to Main instead.

Comment: The back button is not in the toolbar.  Unless you overrode it, then back will go back to "Other".  Up, however, is quite different from Back.  See the Android documentation I linked on the topic.

Comment: Yes, I mean the "Up" button in the toolbar. I'll adjust my question.

Comment: Please paste Manifest file.

Comment: I posted my Manifest File but my question is more in the abstract sense. I tried to adjust the NAMES to better reflect question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `android support library` you can see the class `NavUtils`

From the javadoc

> NavUtils provides helper functionality for applications implementing
>    recommended Android UI navigation patterns

**Reference** http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/v4/app/NavUtils.html

Answer (score 0):

Engraver is actually right not sure why got down voted. When you press the UP button (back arrow in the toolbar) in your ReusableActivity you can call `finish()` the ReusableActivity will close and the last Activity will pop up which will be either MainActivity or OtherActivity from your diagram.

That said, you need to override `onOptionsItemSelected` to be notified when the UP button in the toolbar is pressed.

Also make sure yout call `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` on the activity to show the up button.

**ReusableActivity**

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home: // Notice the id for the up button
            finish(); // Up button pressed so call finish.
            return(true);
    }

    return(super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
}
```

**NOTE:**

You might want to remove the meta tag from the ReusableActivity in the manifest to avoid confusion as to what the parent activity will be since it will be overriden programatically.

**Alternative**

If for some reason you don't want to call `finish()` you can start a new activity instead. This intent will make sure to start the previous activity so you don't need to keep track.

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
startActivity(i);
```

**You should pass the launcher activity to the intent (MainActivity.class), regardless of what activity will be actually started, the action and category in the intent will take care of starting the right activity**

**EDIT:**

**Since you were having issues getting it to work I added this alternative.**

You can try this other method, when you start ReusableActivity through an intent pass the class of the Activity that is launching ReusableActivity and when the up button is pressed simply start that Activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ReusableActivity.class);
//the activity you want to start when pressing the up button
intent.put("parent", MainActivity.this);
startActivity(intent);
```

Do the same when starting ReusableActivity from OtherActivity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(OtherActivity.this, ReusableActivity.class);
//the activity you want to start when pressing the up button
intent.put("parent", OtherActivity.this);
startActivity(intent);
```

Now when the up button is pressed on OptionsActivity you will be able to start the correct activity.

**OptionsActivity**

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:

            Class<?> parentActivityClass = (Class<?>)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("parent");
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, parentActivityClass);
            startActivity(intent);

            return(true);
    }

    return(super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
}
```

Comment: Hmm.... this didn't work. I made sure to remove the full meta tag. The Reusable still returns to the MainActivity.

Comment: did you override onOptionsItemSelected inside ReusableActivity or in some other activity? can you add a log after calling finish to make sure it is being called.

Comment: I overrode in Reusable. I did log it and it is called. But still returns to Main

Comment: That is interesting. I tested it and works for me. I am extending AppCompatActivity, using the support library.

Comment: I am extending that as well.

Comment: Look at my edit. I added an alternative at the end, see it that works for you.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure I understand your question. Just call `finish()` when the user presses the back arrow?